# Imprimir palabras que empiecen con la letra S

Tags: python, bucle-for

empecé hace unas semanas en todo esto de la programación, pero resulta que tengo una pregunta en un test de un curso online, que dice:
Usando "for", "split" e "if", crea una sentencia que imprime las palabras que empiecen con S

Al momento se me ocurrió una forma y creo que está bien en el planteamiento, pero fallo en la sintaxis.

```
palabra_s = input("Ingrese una palabra que comienze con S...")

for string in palabra_s:
    mi_lista = string.split()

if mi_lista[0] == "S" or mi_lista[0] == "s":
    print ("Bien hecho")

else:
    pass
```

Mi problema (creo) está en el if, lo que pasa es que le pongo [0] a la lista, para que sea solo el primer caracter el que me pida la S, pero resulta que si pongo una palabra no pasa nada (ni me tira error).Si solo le escribo una S (o "s" minúscula) en vez de una palabra completa me retorna el print positivo.
Como lo arreglo? Creo que nadie formuló alguna así que me anime a hacer mi primera pregunta..
Gracias de antemano!!!

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en el `for`, el valor `mi_lista` solo es el último carácter de la cadena ingresada. La función `append()` sirve para agregar cosas a la lista. Entonces una manera sería:

```
palabra_s = input("Ingrese una palabra que comienze con S...")
mi_lista = []
for string in palabra_s:
    mi_lista.append(string)

if mi_lista[0] == "S" or mi_lista[0] == "s":
    print ("Bien hecho")
else:
    pass
```

Otra manera sería con la función `startswith(x)`, esta retorna un valor de True o False si la cadena empieza con `x`, y ya tendría caso separar por carácter.

```
if palabra_s.startswith("S") or palabra_s.startswith("s"):
    print ("Bien hecho")
else:
    pass
```

Espero haberte ayudado! Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Bienvenidos a StackOverflow. El metodo `split()` sin argumentos cambia la cuerda a una lista de palabras. El indice `0` de `mi_lista` representa una palabra entera. Para ver la primera letra de la primera palabra de `mi_lista`, hay que poner otro indice: `mi_lista[0][0]` o accederla dentro de una for loop.

Si le entiendo bien, quiere cambiar la frase a una lista de palabras y imprimir la palabras que empiecen con "S".

Le recomiendo algo asi:

```
frase = input("Ingrese una palabra que comienze con S...")

palabras = frase.split()

for palabra in palabras:
    if (palabra[0] == "S" or palabra[0] == "s"):
        print(palabra)
```